# No webpack.config.js file created with "tns create example-app" command

Tags: android, nativescript-angular

I've followed the instructions for environment creation from the official Nativescript page, but when creating the app with "tns create example-app", there is no webpack.config.js created.
When running "tns run android", I get the following error:

```
The webpack configuration file C:\Users\Userx\Desktop\Nativescript-Introduction-Project\example-app\webpack.config.js does not exist. Ensure the file exists, or update the path in nativescript.config.(js|ts).
```

When running `npm config get ignore-scripts`, as suggested in another thread, the result is false.
My Node version is 18.15.0 LTS, the OS is Windows 10.
Did anyone else has encountered this issue?

- Ran `tns create example-app`, no "webpack.config.js" created